# Not getting List of Shipping Services

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, php-5.4, shipping-methods

i'm new to magento. In my custom module I'm getting list of available shipping methods.

Shipping Methods are getting but available shipping services are not getting.

my code is:

```
<?php

class Easylife_Ship_Model_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
{
    public function services()
    {

      $servers =  $this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('India')
            ->setCity('Hyderabad')->setPostcode('500073')->setRegion('Andhra Pradesh')
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                 //$this->getQuote()->save();
        return $servers;

    }

    protected function _getCart()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    }

    public function shpmethods()
    {
        $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

        $options = array();

        foreach($methods as $_code => $_method)
        {
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_code/title"))
                $_title = $_code;

            $options[] = array('value' => $_code, 'label' => $_title . " ($_code)");
        }


        return $options;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted 'shpmethods()' and not 'shipmethods()'?

Comment: @user2045, I want `shipmethods()`.any way I got result of `shipmethods()'. Now how can i get available `shipping services` based on address.

Comment: I just happened to notice that you misspelled shipmethods in your function definition.

Answer (score 1):

getActiveCarriers will return a list of carriers with their carrierCode and their associated model. Its not going to return the shipping methods.

To get these you need to call getAllowedMethods() on each of the carrier models.  You will then get a list of carrier methods.